# How to submit select without post req?

Tags: php, select

How can I change to case 1 or case 2 when I change this first options I, IV and V without submiting POST request?

```
<select name="vrsta_predmenta">
    <option value="1">I</option>
    <option value="2">IV</option>
    <option value="3">V</option>
</select>
<select name="izvrsenje">
<?php
    switch($_POST['vrsta_predmenta']){
        case 1:
            echo '<option value="1">Prvo izvrsenje</option>';
            echo '<option value="2">Drugo izvrsenje</option>';
            echo '<option value="3">Trece izvrsenje</option>';
            break;
        case 2:
            echo '<option value="1">Cetvrto izvrsenje</option>';
            echo '<option value="2">Peto izvrsenje</option>';
            echo '<option value="3">Sesto izvrsenje</option>';
            break;

    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Without reloading the page, you would need some javascript

Comment: You want send data if changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need javascript for this. Here is an example of very simple approach when you have all your options already in place but hidden, and you show necessary depending on the selected option in the main selectbox.

```js
var main = document.querySelector('.main'),
    secondary = document.querySelector('.secondary');

main.onchange = function() {
    var mainValue = main.options[main.selectedIndex].value;
    [].slice.call(secondary.options).forEach(function(option) {
        option.hidden = option.className !== 'value-' + mainValue;
    });
    
    secondary.options[0].hidden = false;
    secondary.options[0].selected = true;
};
```

```html
<select name="vrsta_predmenta" class="main">
    <option value="1">I</option>
    <option value="2">IV</option>
    <option value="3">V</option>
</select>

<select name="izvrsenje" class="secondary">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="1" class="value-1" hidden>Prvo izvrsenje</option>
    <option value="2" class="value-1" hidden>Drugo izvrsenje</option>
    <option value="3" class="value-1" hidden>Trece izvrsenje</option>
    <option value="1" class="value-2" hidden>Cetvrto izvrsenje</option>
    <option value="2" class="value-2" hidden>Peto izvrsenje</option>
    <option value="3" class="value-2" hidden>Sesto izvrsenje</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How can I remove selected option form 2. select when option in 1. select changed? When I change from I to IV first option in second select still stay 'Prvo izvrsenje'....

Answer (score 0):

You are currently mixing html and php.

For what you need, you need to implement javascript inside your html page. Your code will not work because php is on server side, not on client side.

Comment: Do you have some example?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<select name="vrsta_predmenta" id='sendRequest'>
                            <option value="1" >I</option>
                            <option value="2">IV</option>
                            <option value="3">V</option>
                        </select>


jQuery('#sendRequest').change(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:'your php file url',
        type:'post',
        data:{data:jQuery(this).val()},
        dataType:'JSOON',
        success:function(){
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: I need to get antoher options in another select depend on that option above.